# Logging line numbers of the java code which has executed

Tags: java, code-coverage

I am developing an application. As a part of this, when the Java program executes, we want to display line numbers of the source of the Java program where the code has executed. I'm using the Code class to get the line number of the methods in the code. But I want to get the line number of the source that have been executed,that is ,code path.

I will add to this, the program I have written to display the line numbers of the methods.

```
class LineNum
{
  LineNumber[] ln = new LineNumber[300];
  JavaClass clazz ;
  Code classinfo ;

  public static void printCode(Method[] methods) {
    System.out.println("Entering PrintCode");
    for(int i=0; i < methods.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(methods[i]);

      Code code = methods[i].getCode();
      if(code != null) // Non-abstract method
      {  
        System.out.println(code.getLineNumberTable());
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LineNum liner = new LineNum();
    liner.clazz = Repository.lookupClass("package_name.File_name");
    printCode(liner.clazz.getMethods());
  }
}
```

Comment: Dont you need just line-feed and carriage-return wide-chars?

Comment: I would use a code coverage tool like emma or covertura. http://emma.sourceforge.net/ Some IDEs have this builtin so you can see this information in your editor.

Comment: I just need the line feed. And I was asked to implement an application like covertura.Hence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
StackTraceElement[] ele = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

an any time which gives you the previously calls. The StackTraceElement class has a method getLineNumer() to get the line number.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

Comment: Sorry, but thats a bad idea, because creating a Stacktrace is cpu-extensive.

Comment: I tried this. ele.getLineNumber() returns the line number of the source line containing the execution point represented by this stack trace element. Hence it prints only the line number where the  getStackTrace() is called.I called getStackTrace() in the last statement. Please correct me if I've gone wrong anywhere.

Thank you Don.

Comment: Yes you are right. Using the stack trace you can examine a delegation hierarchy, looking up the lines of code where a method was called. You cannot trace the code line of a call like System.out.println(); I mean you can call getStackTrace in the next line and then use getLineNumber()-1, but this is not very elegant. And note what Mirko already posted, steadily creating Stack Traces consumes some CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Log4J as your logging library, you can configure it to output the line number as part of the pattern. See 'PatternLayout' and the 'L' conversion pattern character.

You could use a conversion pattern like: `"%-5p [%t](%L): %m%n"` to yield:

```
   DEBUG [main](103): Message 1
   WARN  [main](104): Message 2
```

PatternLayout API: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: Suppose the downside of this, is you'd have to litter the rest of your application with possibly unnecessary logging output...

Comment: Thank you @bazwilliams. You're answer is very helpful but speed is an issue for me and 'L' conversion character states that 'should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using lo4j is best solution (how it is described by @bazwilliams). Code is depended on simple library and logging line numbers can be optional configured outside of code.

@bazwilliams - you can configure layout pattern only for selected logging category (thus configuring selected appender).

PS. I answered because I didn't know how to comment @bazwilliams answer (or I couldn't).